# Generate User List From AV output File In Bash

Tags: bash

I want to generate list of users having malware in their public html

I am using avgscan for scanning,

```
/opt/avg/av/bin/avgscan -a -c --ignerrors --report=avoutput.txt
```

but it generates report like

```
/home/someuser/mail/info/cur/1395054106.H396740P84180,S=47470:2,S:/form_ident.rar  Trojan horse Inject2.WPP
/home/someuser/public_html/__swift/files/attach_pq2ar348en1z435o5jhqy37de2xfb391  Trojan horse Zbot.BMI
```

I tried some thing but it didnt workout as list also have /backup folder which I don't want to be counted in list
I just need list of users, how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
    in="your_av_report file.txt" # in this case avoutput.txt

    a=$(cat $in | grep -i "/mail/" | grep -v "/backup/" | cut -d'/' -f3 | awk '!a[$0]++' | uniq)
    b=$cat $in | grep -i "/public_html/" | grep -v "/backup/" | cut -d'/' -f3 | awk '!a[$0]++' | uniq)
    echo $a >>foo.txt
    echo $b >>foo.txt
```

I hope it Helps :)

Comment: @AvinashRaj It represents list should be unique, I mean if in his output there are two or more malware in same user then same user's name will be listed twice or more, so to avoid that.. Btw | uniq means the same, I used both